# Magento2 multi-store view memory issue

Tags: magento2, memory-leak

I have a two websites I just merged to be one magento2.2.5 based multi-site. One website but multi-store views. Now when I login as one of my test customers on one website view it works however if i test logging into the site as a customer on another store view I get a blank white page and when I view my server error log I see the below.

```
Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291
```

However this is a aws ec2 server that has 60Gig of RAM so idk why or how I could be out of memory . the sites worked fine when they were independent.

Suggestions for how i can troubleshoot what might be causing the memory issue?